# Отфильтровать таблицу в Google Sheets по двум значениям одного столбца

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть столбец в таблице:

| ID клиента |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| (blank) |
| (blank) |
| (blank) |

Какую формулу использовать в фильтре, чтобы в выдаче остались строки со значением "3" и пустые (blank)? Решение отметить галочками нужные пункты не подходит, нужна именно формула. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отдельный столбец

```
=ИЛИ(A2="";A2=3)
```

Фильтр по этому столбцу

Comment: А есть ли решение без создания отдельного столбца? Задумка в том, чтобы раздать пользователям ссылки на фильтры, и чтобы они сами указывали свой ID, и в своей таблице (фильтре) видели каждый свои строки + пустые. Пользователей много и они часто прибавляются. С добавлением столбца будет труднее менеджерить таблицу. Гораздо проще поправить одно значение в формуле к одному столбцу и сгенерить ссылку на этот фильтр для нового пользователя

Comment: *Гораздо проще поправить одно значение в формуле* - полностью согласен. Заменить в формуле цифру 3 на ссылку на ячейку, в которой указан ID. Пользователям достаточно вписать свой ID в одну ячейку

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение подошло